# Getting Openssl "close notify" without an "SSL_read", it there a way?

Tags: sockets, openssl, raspbian

I've recently upgraded a BLE packet capture application running on a Raspberry Pi Zero/w (Raspbian Stretch) to use OpenSSL when forwarding packets to a cloud server. The cloud server just receives the packets and stores them in a db, the app on the Pi just sends the packets to the cloud server. So it's a one-way conversation from the Pi to the cloud server.

The problem is that the cloud server will shutdown a connection after a period of inactivity. So it calls `SSL_shutdown()`, but on the Pi the `SSL_RECEIVED_SHUTDOWN` flag never gets set, unless I call `SSL_read()` (or peek).

Additionally, polling on the socket doesn't show `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` on the Pi, even after the server has made it's call.

So, bottom line, I'm having to constantly call `SSL_read()` just to catch the shutdown. Is that normal? Is there another approach that makes more sense?

I'm using non-blocking sockets, so it doesn't seem to hurt anything, but it just seems hokey since the cloud server is never going to be sending any data (so there's never going to be anything to actually read).

Anyway, I've spent hours researching and trying various approaches, but this is the only way I've found to get it to work.

Comment: Do the peek at suitable intervals.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, that's pretty much what I'm doing now I just wasn't sure if there was another way to go about it. Just kind of surprised since at the beginning of the connection all the handshaking is down without the app needing to do anything. I thought the same would go for the shutdown but all just speculation on my part...

Comment: An SSL handshake is bidirectional, there are multiple packets sent back and forth in both directions. OpenSSL handles all of that for you. But once the handshake is finished, all of your subsequent traffic is one direction - outbound. If your don't try to read inbound data periodically, you will never receive a shutdown alert. `SSL_write()` won't try to read inbound packets unless it is expecting them, such as during renegotiation. So you will have to call `SSL_read()` periodically yourself.

Comment: Thanks! About what I suspected but I wanted to be sure before I just left it that way. As I mentioned the sockets are non-blocking so I guess it doesn't do any harm to try a read every half second or so. Again, thanks to all that replied, it's good to have a definitive answer...

Comment: I think your reply can be marked as the "answer" but I don't appear to have that ability yet.